# Reading and writing TCP header (options) in Java

Tags: java, networking, tcp, header

What I'm trying to do is:
Writing client and server for sending a String via TCP with Java, so far no problem using Socket and Input-/Output-Streams.

But now I'm trying to add 3 numbers to the "Options" field in the tcp header [image]. I can't find any helpful tutorials or something else on how to customize the header and how to read it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653262/how-to-write-custom-data-to-the-tcp-packet-header-options-field-with-java

Comment: Trying to add what three numbers? Why? The only things in the header that are any of your business have APIs to set them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't:

- at application level, you do not have access to the TCP headers;
- Java does not have raw sockets either.

You can somewhat influence *some* of the TCP behavior by setting different socket options, though. But not manipulating TCP headers directly.

Answer (score 1):

Not without utilizing external library like jNetPcap.
jNetPcap does allow you to format and send your own packet.

[jNetPcap Installation Guide (Eclipse)](http://jnetpcap.com/eclipse)

[jNetPcap Installation Guide (NetBeans)](http://jnetpcap.com/netbeans)

A very rough sample code for [formatting and sending packet](http://jnetpcap.com/examples/sendpacket).
Rough it may be, but it shows you the possibilities to customize the packet.

Edit:
Forgot to mention that jNetPcap is a Java wrapper for libpcap. They are meant to be utilized to read the packet in the first place.