# How to obtain TCP header from socket's inputStream() in Android?

Tags: java, android, tcp

Android/Java provides socket APIs for receiving data from TCP server, like:

```
socket.getInputStream().read(payload);
```

The payload is data stripped off TCP header as well as IP header. My question is that possible to get the TCP header?  Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to this question/answer on SO [reading-and-writing-tcp-header-options-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267923/reading-and-writing-tcp-header-options-in-java) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access TCP headers as explained here: [Reading and writing TCP header (options) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267923/reading-and-writing-tcp-header-options-in-java)

The thing is that without monitoring your network, you won't be able to access that information from the Java API.

What you might want to try is looking at this library if you really need the TCP headers http://jnetpcap.com.

This library is able to read the packets in real time. You would just have to match the packet you received with your socket in Java to the correct packet received by the library.

Comment: From Java/Android description, it's truly unable to obtain stripped header. Thanks.

Comment: I've just seen that you intend to use it on Android. The library might not be able to work on Android because of the architecture of the system.

Comment: I would prefer to get header info using C, which is faster than Java to take care of memory and pointers.

Comment: @frogcd have you found any way to read tcp header in android without root privilege?