# Tag the application type in a network packet

Tags: networking, packet, pcap, traffic

Lets say I have a pcap capture that contains a mintue of Youtube video and a minute of a skype call. I also know exactly which packets belong to which application. Is there a way to tag a field in any of the headers of the packet to say that it belongs to a specific application.

Basically what I'm asking is that is there a way to tag a packet by adding additional information in a header field. At the same time I dont want to break any RFCs.

Thank you

Comment: you mean that you want to modify packets headers on the fly?

Comment: Either on the fly or in post processing. I want to know where would it be possible to add this extra bit of information in the packet.

Comment: Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you should have some kind of proxy that modifies tcp packet headers before passing it through.

there are some suggestions here:
[How to write custom data to the TCP packet header options field with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653262/how-to-write-custom-data-to-the-tcp-packet-header-options-field-with-java)
[how to modify packet header(IP header, TCP Header) before the host send them into the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428694/how-to-modify-packet-headerip-header-tcp-header-before-the-host-send-them-int)

you can also check this guide, it have section how to add extra headers info into packets:
http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/tcpproxy.html

is this applicable to your case?